# piping in shell implementation in C

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I am implementing a shell in C. This is the function i use for piping. When i put     "ls | a" in the code (i.e. pipe a valid command with invalid one),It doesnt exit the child process like it should. How do i make it go back to main function? 
same thing happens when i do      ps | ls or     ps | pwd etc. but     ls | ps works the same as in bash. i know      ls | ps or      ps | ls dont make sense but atleast they should give same output as bash.

```
void exec3(char **args, char **args2){
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid,pid1;
    int status;
    pipe(fd);
    int e=0;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {    
        printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0) {    
        printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    else if (pid == 0 && pid1!=0){   
        printf("in 1\n");
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);

            if(execvp(args[0],args)<0){
                printf("**error in exec");
                close(fd[0]); 
                close(fd[1]);           
                exit(1);
            }
    //printf("exiting 1\n");
    exit(0);
}

else if (pid1 == 0 && pid!=0) {   
    printf("in 2\n");
    close(0);
    dup(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    if((e=execvp(args2[0],args2))<0){
            printf("**error in exec2 ");
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd[1]);

        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}

else {  
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        fflush(stdout) ;             
        while (wait(&status) != pid);
        while (wait(&status) != pid1);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Read a good book like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ and study the source code of some small free software shell like `sash`.

Comment: Quick question : are you from epitech? :)

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr.  `printf( "ERROR...` is *always* wrong.  `perror` is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

You are close to the solution. Look at how `popen()` [is implemented](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/src/lib/libc/gen/popen.c), that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: actually i found it but its very complicated, above my level. I would appreciate if u could just point out the mistake.